# Active Reports chartcontrol giving error

Tags: c#-4.0, report, activereports, componentone

I have created a report in Active Reports (.rpx file) which contains a chartcontrol 'ChartControl1'.
Report Datasource is List which contains 'ItemLabel' and 'ItemValue' fields
Script file contains following line of code.

```
public void ActiveReport_ReportStart()
{
    this.ChartControl1.DataSource = rpt.DataSource;
    this.ChartControl1.Series[0].ValueMemberX = "ItemLabel";
    this.ChartControl1.Series[0].ValueMembersY = "ItemValue";
}
```

Apparently i am getting an error which says

> "DataSource of type System.String is not supported .Parameter name:
>   genericDataSource"

and this line is causing the problem.

```
this.ChartControl1.Series[0].ValueMembersY = "ItemValue";
```

because if i remove this line , there is no error , but report would not render.
I have read that this error is happening due to incorrect binding , but it is not the case here as i have doublechecked it.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually observed when a string value is assigned to the ValueMemebersY property of chart series, where the string value is not a valid field/column name in the table that is bound to the chart as it’s datasource.

Please refer to the [walkthrough](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arWLKSimpleUnboundChart.html) which describes how to create an unbound bar chart at runtime with SectionReports (Rpx as well as code based)

You can additionally refer the [charting sample](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/AR7Help/OnlineEn/arSAMChartingSample.html) that is shipped along with ActiveReports.

You may also refer to the following forum post wherein a sample has been attached showing a similar implementation:
http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/chart-control-throwing-a-binding-error/

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: I have double checked to confirm that string value attached is a valid field in the datasource. Could you please check the lat post in following link
[link] http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/datasource-of-type-system-string-is-not-supported-on-bar-chart/

Comment: DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ItemLabel", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("ItemValue", typeof(double));
    table.Rows.Add("Won", 5.0);
    table.Rows.Add("Lost", 7.0);            
    this.chartControl1.DataSource = table;
    this.chartControl1.Series[0].ValueMemberX = "ItemLabel";
    this.chartControl1.Series[0].ValueMembersY = ItemValue";

i have added same code in rpx and codebased report containing chart.but rpx throws error each time , while no issue in codebased sample.why is that?

Answer (score 0):

NewtonCode

what version of product are you using? version 7 or 8?  Its a bug.  we are going to fix it.

Comment: We are using version 7

Comment: What we have found out that one particular node gets written out is not correct.  How did you generate the rpx?

This node is:
 <DataSourceDirect>        
</DataSourceDirect>

But generally, if we create a chart, the DataSourceDirect should be written like this,

<DataSourceDirect special-value="null" />

That special-value="null" attribute/value pair is missing.  There are some special handling that are done based on the presence or absence of that attribute.

Let me know.  thanks.

Comment: I generated rpx from visual studio (addnew->sectionreportxmlbased).i havent edited the rpx file to remove that attribute.need to investigate under what condition the attribute dissapears.

I have now edited the rpx to include attribute 'special-value=null' to DataSourceDirect node  ( in my test i uploaded ) and it still is showing same error.

Comment: k thanks.  Will let the team know and see what they have to say.

Comment: Can you also tell us what build number you have installed please.  Are you able to reproduce this consistently?  We have been trying all different ways to reproduce a rpx with the errant datasourcedirect node, but so far we have been unsuccessful. Is there a specific step in there for chart? just drag the chart on the designer?  Do you something else after that?